# Upgrading OBIEE 11.1.6 to 12C

Tags: oracle, upgrade, weblogic12c, business-intelligence, obiee

I am going to upgrade my OBIEE app which has 11.1.1.6 version to 12C version(12.2.1.3 or 12.2.14).
By searching on the internet, I have found some valuable documents or articles with regard to upgrade from 11.1.1.7 to 12C(not 11.1.1.6). As there are mostly tangible and fundamental changes from one version rather than higher one (when new version is released by Oracle co.), especially in terms of architecture, my concern is that it is possible to upgrade from 11.1.1.6 to 12C ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an upgrade directly from 11.1.1.6 to 12.2.1.4 is NOT supported. You shouldn't even try to use 12.2.1.3 anymore as it is an old 12c version.

You must do 11.1.1.6 to 11.1.1.7 or 11.1.1.9 (better 11.1.1.9) and then upgrade to 12.2.1.4.

Comment: Does this answer your question then?

Comment: Actually yes for now because I just was going to make a plan to do this matter. So this question was with regard to checking possibility. It is likely to have some difficulties during upgrading but not now. Thanks again